# Go io reader wrapper

Tags: go

I have written the following code which tries to cipher the alpha numberic characters by 13. This is an example in the tour of go. 
I have used the log library to check out the values in the byte array p, after the cipher, and they seem to be rotated by 13. For some reason when it prints to STDOUT, the characters are not ciphered.
I am altering byte array p incorrectly?

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func cipher(in byte) (out byte) {
    out = in
    if in > 64 && in < 91 {
        out = in - 64
        out = out + 13
        out = out % 26
        out = out + 64
    }
    if in > 96 && in < 123 {
        out = in - 96
        out = out + 13
        out = out % 26
        out = out + 96
    }
    return
}

func (reader rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for index := range p {
        p[index] = cipher(p[index])
    }
    n, err = reader.r.Read(p)
    return
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader(
        "Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!\n")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `rot13Reader.Read` method, you are first applying `cipher` to whatever data was in `p` and then overwriting that data by reading from the sub-Reader.

If the aim is to decode what you read, you should perform these two operations in the opposite order.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem